# How to prevent [a-z] type regex to match control characters

Tags: php, regex

recently I've been using [a-z] class range regexp in php. I don't know why, but instead of matching only a to z chars, it also matches control characters.
Exemple:

```
preg_match("#^[a-z]{0,3}$#", "aa\n")
```

is returning 1. (I'm on php 5.6).
I would like to prevent the controls characters matched. I've done a few tests with [:^cntrl:] without much succcess.
Could someone help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because `\n` is *end of line* which is matched by `$`.

Comment: @ClasG: To clarify: `$` is a zero-width anchor, so it doesn't match the `\n` character itself but the *position* before a `\n` - the end of the line, as you correctly stated.

Comment: @TimPietzcker True. It's the presence of the `\n` that's "causing" the match though. That's what I was getting at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` anchor may match at the end of the string, or before a final newline in a string.

Use a `/D` *`PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY`* modifier:

```
preg_match("#^[a-z]{0,3}$#D", "aa\n")
                         ^
```

Or `\z` anchor that matches at the *very end* of the string:

```
preg_match("#^[a-z]{0,3}\z#", "aa\n")
```

[PHP test](https://ideone.com/o0fBWi):

```
echo preg_match("#^[a-z]{0,3}$#", "aa\n");  // => 1
echo preg_match("#^[a-z]{0,3}$#D", "aa\n"); // => 0
echo preg_match("#^[a-z]{0,3}\z#", "aa\n"); // => 0
```